# Map refresh with parameters on button click

Tags: google-maps, parameters, reload

I have google map, that is working fine. I have function "load", which is initializing this map. But I need to reload this map on button click. And reload it with some parameters.

When I use "load", map is realoading. But when I use "load()", nothing happens. It is the same, when I use "load(parameter)".

Initialize Google map

```
function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng( 10 , 10),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControl: true,
        zoomControl: true
      });
     // etc ...
     // It works fine...
}
```

jQuery - working

```
 $('button').on('click',load );
 // map is reloading
```

jQuery - doesn't working

```
 $('button').on('click',load(parameter) );
 // or without parameter
 // $('button').on('click',load() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is :

jQuery

```
 $('button').click( function(){
    load();
 });
```